# Identifying child window closure, close property changing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect when a child window is closed.  The user opens a pop up and then closes the pop up.  I want to know when the pop up was closed.  It seems like the common solution for this problem is to put a timer on the Window as this question has already been answered in multiple places on stackoverflow and elsewhere on the web.

My problem is that something is changing the close property on my child window and it is not the user closing the window.  What could be causing this?

Here is my code (by the way, I know the AND should be a double ampersand, for some reason SO was not letting me post with them there):

```
var childWindow = window.open(destURL, "thePopUp", "");
var count = 1;
var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
        alert(childWindow.closed.toString() + count.toString());
        if (childWindow && childWindow.closed && count > 5) {
            window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
            handler();
        }
        count++;
    }, 200);
```

This was not working properly so I put an alert in there to try to see what was going on.
The alerts display the following messages:
false1
true2
true3
true4
true5

So somewhere between 1 and 2 the value of the closed property is changing from false to true.  But I'm not doing anything and the window is still open.  So why would it change from false to true?

Comment: Is this your actual code?  I'm surprised you're getting as far as an alert!

Comment: Yes, this is actual code, but substitute the ANDs for &&s.  For some reason stackoverflow was not allowing me to make the post with the &&s.  I am getting 5 alerts in the order shown above.  It is like something is closing the window for me.

Comment: I don't know.  I just tried that code and it works fine for me.

Comment: destURL for me returns a .pdf file.  The window opens as expected.  My alerts are there just to try to test and figure out why it does not work as expected.

Comment: Understood.  But I've run the same code, without `destURL` and `handler()`, and it works perfectly.  This would suggest to me there is an issue with either of those, but not with the code you've shown us.

Comment: At this point handler just has one line of code which is another alert letting me know that it hit the handler.  Here is how I define destURL: var destURL = ScriptResolveUrl("~/Report/GetPDFReport") + "?sid=" + sid;

Comment: Well, there you go. `ScriptResolveUrl` is not JS, so that's probably what's causing problems.  Btw, I've edited your question to substitute `&&` for `AND`.

Comment: Would it be possible to set up a fiddle?

Comment: ScriptResolveUrl is just an internal function we have here which translates the tilda (~) to the proper path for the server.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Because it worked fine for me in chrome. ['Fiddle'](http://jsfiddle.net/zYvVc/) _Warning: makes popup on load._

Comment: I'm using IE8 with ASP.NET MVC and VS2010 as IDE.

Comment: Looks like one of the previous posters is possibly correct.  When I change my destURL to something simple like google.com, it works.

Comment: Sounds like it, as I get it to work in IE8: [Fiddle (Show)](http://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/yCnX8/show/)

Comment: What happens when the PDF file loads? Does it open in the browser or in a viewer application?

Comment: In a viewer application with .pdf controls to print, save, etc.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get somewhere.  If I hard code my destURL:  var destURL = "/Report/GetPDFReport?sid=5";  It does not work.  But If I hard code www.google.com, it semi works.  The jquery works as expected, but google does not get pulled up since it's trying to find myserver/google.com which does not exist

Comment: In IE8 for me, it pulls up a PDF in an in-browser PDF viewer app, but it then creates the odd behaviour you're describing. With standard pages, this doesn't happen, so it appears to be an issue with the pdf viewer application. Note: this doesn't happen in Chrome due to it using it's own viewer implementation. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/yCnX8/3/)

Comment: Interesting, I can't get your fiddle to pull up in IE8, but it works perfectly fine in Firefox

Comment: append `show/` to the Fiddle URL, JSFiddle doesn't work right in IE8.

Comment: got it, now I see what you see.  Looks like there is a possible  issue with the pdf viewer in IE

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that this is an issue with the Acrobat Plugin for IE.

When opening a standard webpage, the code you have posted works as expected. Using the URL of a PDF, however, produces different results in different browsers.

In Chrome, as it uses it's own rendering system for PDFs, the code works as expected. In IE8, however, the PDF viewer plugin appears to report the page as closed.

I have been unable to find a workaround for this as of yet.

Attempts have included defining a closure for `childWindow.onunload` and `childWindow.onbeforeunload`. In Chrome, these trigger the closure function before the window is actually closed.

Check for `childWindow.closed`:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/yCnX8/3/), [For viewing in IE](http://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/yCnX8/3/show/)

Closure:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/yCnX8/5/), [For viewing in IE](http://jsfiddle.net/XGundam05/yCnX8/5/show/)

Comment: " In Chrome, these trigger the closure function before the window is actually closed."     I experience this also in IE.  The unload events get called before the Window is actually closed.